# How can I convert struct value into struct pointer using reflection

Tags: go, reflection, types, interface

The goal is

> Having a variable `B` that satisfies a specific interface `I` through pointer receivers type, create another variable `C` (with reflection and using `B`), copy `B`'s values into `C`,  modify `C` (without changing `B`) and return `C` as type `I`.

Suppose that I have the following types, the following snippets mimic production code:

```
import (
    "reflect"
)

type IFace interface {
    A() 
    B()
    C()
}

type Meta struct {
    s string
}

func (m *Meta) A() {}
func (m *Meta) B() {}
func (m *Meta) C() {}

type One struct {
    M *Meta
    B bool
}

func (o *One) A() {}
func (o *One) B() {}
func (o *One) C() {}
```

And I have a method that does the following:

```
func Alias(src, dest *Meta) (IFace, error) {
    base, err := find(src) //asume that `find` is implemented and err is nil
    if err != nil { 
       return err
    }

    // trouble starts here ...
    // allocate new "instance"
    aliased := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(base)).Elem().Interface()

    // copy the base value
    aliased = base 

    aliasedV := reflect.ValueOf(aliased).Elem()
    fm := aliasedV.FieldByName("M")
    fm.Set(reflect.ValueOf(dest))

    return aliasedV.Interface().(Iface), nil
}
```

It compiles and runs however with the following TestFunction it gives me this error message:

```
interface conversion: One is not IFace: missing method C [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: One is not IFace: missing method C
```

and the test function:

```
func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
   srcID := &Meta{S: "SRC"}
   destID := &Meta{S: "DEST"}
   aliased, err := Alias(srcID, destID)
   if err != nil {
       t.Error(err)
   }

   one, isOne := aliased.(*One)
   if !isOne {
       t.Error("fail")
   }
}
```

Is there a way to have an `interface{}` type that wraps a struct value become an `interface{}` type that wraps a struct pointer without using the underlying struct type directly, like avoiding: `var any interface{} = aliased.(*One)`
??,

Could the `unsafe` package be of help here?

Here is a playground that replicates the panic, thanks to [RayfenWindspear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276480/rayfenwindspear)

https://play.golang.org/p/860uAE7qLc

Comment: Why are you creating an instance with `reflect` then immediately overwriting the variable that contains it?

Comment: To copy the values, of the `base` variable.

Comment: Or at least experimenting with copying it, `reflect.New()` returns a zeroed pointer, and I've haven't found a way to unzero it. I know that currently it will modify the `base` var

Comment: But you already have the `base` variable.... all you are doing is creating a new pointer that points to the same data. Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I need to copy the `base` variable values into the `aliased` one, the intent there is to do something like this `*dest = *src`, `dest` and `src` same type but different pointers., trying to figure out how that would be done without explicitly using each of `base`'s and with the `reflect` package

Comment: I also can't figure out what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but does this get you closer? https://play.golang.org/p/n-G5YwYkaH

Comment: I can't quite figure out either, but in the code I c/p and modified, I get similar output, but `missing method A`. https://play.golang.org/p/860uAE7qLc

Comment: @JimB It helps me replicate the issue faster: https://play.golang.org/p/OsFrEKP-eo

Comment: Updated @RayfenWindspear's link, https://play.golang.org/p/h1cl4FNUGY, is this what you want?

Comment: @mkopriva I added a test to modify the values to your link. The pointers do indeed point to different values. I'd say you are spot on.

Comment: thanks!, @mkopriva it definitely is closer however the `base.M` field is changed to `destID`, see: https://play.golang.org/p/DzQOnjYW2X

Comment: and you want it to be what? What do you expect the output to be? an existing pointer? which one? and pointing to what value? Or a new pointer? pointing to what value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if I understood you correctly, in your updated example from the comments the returned `base` is what you want to copy, modify, and then return the copy of, without changing anything in `base`. If that's the case, this code `aliased = base` is not gonna do what you want if the base's underlying type is a pointer, which is true in this case.

Note, I've modified the var names to better `reflect` your assignment.

```
// Having a variable B that satisfies a specific
// interface I through pointer receivers type.
B, err := find(src)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// create another variable C (with reflection and using B),
C := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(B).Elem())

// copy B's values into C
bv := reflect.ValueOf(B).Elem()
for i :=0; i < bv.NumField(); i++ {
    fv := bv.Field(i)
    if fv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v := reflect.New(fv.Elem().Type()) // allocate a new pointer of the same type as the B's pointer field is pointing to, in this case 'Meta'
        v.Elem().Set(fv.Elem()) // set the newly allocated pointer's value to the same value as B's pointer field is pointing to, in this case 'Meta{S: "SRC"}'
        C.Elem().Field(i).Set(v) // set the newly allocated pointer as the C's field
    } else {
        C.Elem().Field(i).Set(fv) // non pointer field? just set and that's it
    }
    // NOTE: if B's field's have subfields that are pointers you'll have to do this for all of them if you want a deep copy
}

// modify C (without changing B)
C.Elem().FieldByName("M").Elem().FieldByName("S").Set(reflect.ValueOf("Hello, 世界"))
```

Here's the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bGTdy2vYUu

Sorry if this not what you're looking for.

Comment: that is the solution, it is indeed traversing the fields of `B` and copying one by one. I did a small change which is to set the `M` field to `dest` and it works, I'll just add the "deep" copy because `B` will have subfields that are pointers.

Comment: I appreciated the time you put into it!!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help!

Comment: Just as I note, I found a package that performs deep copy: https://github.com/ulule/deepcopier